# In SAPUI5, how can I set a table column width according to another table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, tablecolumn, column-width

I have two tables which I'd like to synchronize in their column widths.
I'm working in SAPUI5, and therefore I have an event that gets fired every time I resize the column of my table.

I'm currently using jQuery to get to my solution but it's not yet working the way I want it. I realize that there have been different questions to the same topic, I've gone through all of them but couldn't find the fitting solution.

Here's my code:

```
oTable.attachColumnResize(function(oEvent) {
    $('.syncScroll tr:eq(1) td').each(function (i) {
         var width = $('.syncScroll td:eq(' + i + ')').width()
         $('.bottom td:eq(' + i + ')').attr('width', width);
        console.log($('.bottom td:eq(' + i + ')').width());
    })                                              
})
```

**synScroll** is the class name of my upper table and **bottom** the name for my lower table. (I can't use IDs since they're predefined from SAPUI5 but the classnames are unique)

The event is fired every time I resize a column, so that part is working fine. But the column width doesn't adjust (checked this by console.log...)

I've tried different solutions on how to set the width of the lower table. 
Attempts so far:

- `$('.bottom td:eq(' + i + ')').width(width);`
- `$('.bottom td:eq(' + i + ')').css('width', width, 'px');`
- `$('.bottom td:eq(' + i + ')').width() = width;` --> causes invalid left-handed argument error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @DubZ, I came to different approaches.

- jQuery doesn't provide the **new** width of a column, but only the width **before** the columnResize()-Event. Therefore, accessing that width won't help during the attachColumnResize()-Event
- SAPUI5 provides a getWidth()-Method for table columns, but this property is empty when the initial value is set to "auto". So this wouldn't help either

My solution: The attachColumnResize()-Event provides two parameters. First, the column that got resized and second, the new width of that column.  So I figure out the index of the resized column in the one table and apply the new width to the column with the same index in the second table. Since columnWidth is set to auto, the other columns will adjust accordingly. 
This is my code:

```
 oTable.attachColumnResize(function(oEvent) {
        //get position of resized column and adjust column with same position in lower table
        let aColumns = oTable.getColumns();
        let eventId = _.trimStart(oEvent.getParameters().column.sId, '__column');
        let lastIndex = _.trimStart(_.nth(aColumns, -1).sId, '__column')
        let nmbrOfColumns = oTable.getColumns().length;
        let positionId = nmbrOfColumns - (lastIndex - eventId) - 1;    
        let oSecondTable = this.getView().byId("generatedTableView").getContent()[0].getContent()[1];                   
        let aSecondColumns = oSecondTable.getColumns();                 
        aSecondColumns[positionId].setWidth(oEvent.getParameters().width);                  
}.bind(this))
```

I feel like this is a bit long-winded, so feel free to let me know any sleeker way!

Answer (score 1):

@sonja you were right. if the column width is not set, then getWidth() is empty.

Here is an update with a mix of jquery and ui5 api:

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("tableName");
var oSecondTable = this.getView().byId("secondTableName");
var aColumns = oTable.getColumns();
var aSecondColumns = oSecondTable.getColumns();

for(var i=0; i<aColumns.length; i++) {
    var columnWidth = $("#"+aColumns[i].getId()).width(); 
    aSecondColumns[i].setWdith(columnWidth);
}
```

Comment: thanks @DubZ !
for some reason, getWidth() results into " " on my side. so it's simply empty.. I see properties such as _iNewWidth or _Width, but that's not exactly a good solution, accessing them..do you have any idea why this might be??


also, there are a few mistakes in your code, in case you'd like to adjust them:
last row it's "setWidth..." and the [i] has to come right after "aColumns"

Comment: ok after doing some research I found out, that there's no value for a columns width when the initial value is set to "auto". and that's the case in my application.. so I can't access the column width like that unfortunately..

Comment: I updated my initial post. have a try if this answers ur question

Comment: Thanks again, I checked this out and my conclusion is that with jQuery, you don't get the "new" column width but only the width BEFORE the column resize. Therefore, I figured out another way. I'll post this as an answer. I'd be thankful if you have a look at it and tell me if this is a "clean" solution for the scenario..

Comment: Hi, I checked this and dont agree. If I do setWidth("200px") and afterwards execute $("#tablecolumn").width(), then it shows me 200. 

maybe you saved $("#tablecolumn").width() into a variable. this will _not_ automatically updated via event or sth.

Comment: oh, let me check that! 
hm ok no, it's the same as before. The column width adjusts always the NEXT time I resize another column. So jQuery doesn't access the new width but the old one..

Comment: ok, sorry I missunderstood you or I didnt recognized the event you searched/wants to  use after resizing was done. like you saw, there is the columnResize event available and the properties width and column. so like you did should be the right way